# How to programmatically set a parent device while creating an Azure IoT Hub device?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have written code to programmatically add new IoT devices to my Iot Hub.  Using the Azure Portal it's possible to set a parent device for an Iot Device.

[Setting parent device on Azure portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX3RK.png)

Looking at the documentation and source code on GitHub for the azure-sdk-for-net I don't see away to set a parent device while creating a new device or for setting the parent device on an existing device.

Is there an API for setting the parent device on IoT devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have it available in the public-preview branch of the C# SDK.  For reference, this is the [commit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/commit/2705938c873ad2227274dfba480f13883bf46adb#diff-41108a341698508899af777aee0096f4).

Comment: Thanks!  Exactly what I was looking for. Updating to the latest public preview and setting the Scope property on my newly created device did the trick.