# Programmatically declare a parent-child relationship between the devices in IoT Hub using Node SDK

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-node-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Using the Node SDK, I have programmatically created devices in IoT Hub. I wish to know if the Node SDK provides me the capability to set a device as a child of another device.

Looking at the documentation, I didn't find a way (using SDK). Is there any other way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see and as you found, the SDK doesn't let you create parent/child relationships for devices (https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/azure-iothub/devicescreateorupdateidentityoptionalparams?view=azure-node-latest).

However, the REST API does support this using the `deviceScope` parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/create-or-update-identity).

You might find more information here: [How to programmatically set a parent device while creating an Azure IoT Hub device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463074/how-to-programmatically-set-a-parent-device-while-creating-an-azure-iot-hub-devi)

Comment: Can you please explain in detail (maybe with a small example) how can I use deviceScope  parameter. I had checked the question you have linked, the answer on the question refers to C# SDK which has this feature and I am looking for the same in Node

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked! For anybody who is still stuck on this. I had followed this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792034/azure-iot-edge-programmaticallynodejs-create-parent-child-relation-between-edg